# Automate eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any way to automate below activities for eclipse? Currently all these activities we are doing manually so wanted to know is there any way to automate these.

1. Checkout SVN project in eclipse.
2. After checkout the project perform "mvn clean build eclipse:eclipse" command.
3. Import the projects in eclipse.
4. From run configuration add Java application to run the project.
5. Copy war file to tomcat directory and start tomcat server.

Comment: Why must the application run inside eclipse? You should use maven for everything.

Comment: 1-3 can be or something similar can be done with Buckminster. 4 launch configs can be exportedîmported. 5 probably there is a Buckminster plugin for that, but there might be other options, like a maven target.

Comment: **This falls solidly under the [`X Y Problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/148287) and is off-topic as such.** Especially since Maven can do all this without Eclipse!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you write an Eclipse plugin that does what you want, the answer is: **No**.

**However**, you can automate some parts of it.
For example:

**Ad 1)**
You can import projects to Eclipse directly from *Version Control* by running: `Import => Git => Projects from Git`. This is also available for CVS and Subversion (assuming you have svn plugin installed).

**Ad 2, 3, 5)**
Since you have a mavenized project already, you can import it to Eclipse as `Import => Maven => Existing Maven Projects`. You can also utilize `maven-release-plugin` together with `Jenkins` in order to automate builds of releases and deployments to the application servers.

Using `Jenkins` for automation is a specifically good idea, as this will allow you to define - for example - such flow:

1. You push changes to remote Git repository that Jenkins is set to observe.
2. Jenkins picks up changes and runs a build (using maven, so all the unit and integration test are executed)
3. If the build fails, you'll get notified via email
4. If the build succeeds, the artifacts are deployed to your snapshots repository, and deployed to Tomcat on your Development and Test environments.